# Setting mongodb editor path in mongorc on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to set the path to sublime text editor for mongodb in the .mongorc.js on windows 8 so I add this line to .mongorc.js ...

```
EDITOR = "C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe";
```

which when I start mongo.exe from the command prompt and then type:

```
> edit blah
```

it returns:

```
'C\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

so I try

```
EDITOR = "C:\\Program\u0020Files\\Sublime\u0020Text\u00203\\sublime_text.exe";
```

and even

```
EDITOR = "C:\\Program%20Files\\Sublime%20Text%203\\sublime_text.exe";
```

and I get

The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: it works fine, your escaping wasn't quote complete - you need " " around the name that's escaped so that it's preserved.  I just added an answer showing how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the path cannot include spaces.

The simplest workaround for this is to use the generated 8.3 names for the folders rather than the path with spaces.

From a command prompt, you'll use the `/x` switch which displays the normally hidden 8.3 directory and file names:

```
c:
cd \
dir pro* /x
```

Should return something like this:

```
Directory of C:\

11/05/2013  07:19 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
11/05/2013  07:19 PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
```

If you're using the 64 bit version of Sublime, you'd choose `PROGRA~1`.

Change to the `Program Files` directory:

```
cd Program Files
```

Then, find the Sublime folder's 8.3 name:

```
C:\Program Files>dir Subl* /x

 Directory of C:\Program Files

 09/08/2013  02:17 PM    <DIR>          SUBLIM~1     Sublime Text 2
```

On my system, it's `SUBLIM~1`. Then, change the EDITOR value, using the values from your system to something like:

```
EDITOR="C:\\PROGRA~1\\SUBLIM~1\\sublime_text.exe"
```

You could also create a junction somewhere (without spaces), but the above trick should work fine (I tested it on my machine and it works correctly). The only issue with using Sublime I've noticed is that the `edit` command in the MongoDB console waits for the entire editor process to exit, so you can't use tabs for example.

Comment: I would think the simplest workaround would be to add sublime_text.exe to your default path and then assign just the executable name to EDITOR.

Comment: I wouldn't ... I don't like adding that type of application to my path. I'm not sure why you came along and down voted this. At the time this was asked, I don't know that it worked correctly -- as you can see from the results in the question.

Comment: The first sentence in your answer is not accurate.  I pointed out in my answer that the escaping works just fine - the OP didn't add escaped quotes - the reason I came to this question is someone filed a bug in mongodb jira to "fix" the behavior based on this question, so I added an answer so that people would know how to do it.   As you can see from my example, this already works (and it works in all versions of mongo shell/Windows.

Comment: At the time I wrote this, it did not work. I confirmed it was broken before taking the time to write up the long answer as a work-around.

Comment: the syntax the OP has doesn't work, true - my syntax is different.  It took me about 8 tries before I got the combination of escaping and not escaping correctly - it's non-trivial, but it hasn't changed in any version in the last few years.

Answer (score 7):

You can have spaces in your editor name, you just have to be sure to escape everything properly.   I don't have the editor you have installed, so I used wordpad.

```
> EDITOR="\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows NT\\Accessories\\wordpad.exe\""
"C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"
> edit a
```

works for me.   You need to enclose the whole thing in quotes, and then backslash escape backslashes and double quotes around the entire executable.

You can also make sure the path to your editor is in your default/system path, then you only need to assign the editor executable name to EDITOR.